# Can a cubic spline be both relaxed and clamped?

Tags: spline

I am curious if a spline can be both relaxed (second derivative = 0 at both endpoints) and clamped (first derivative is explicitly defined at both endpoints). This only needs to be true for a single spline between two end points. If this is not possible, what power (quartic, quintic, etc.) of spline would be required to fulfill these conditions?

Either way, how would I go about calculating a spline that fulfills these conditions?

I know very little about splines, so I may be missing something obvious. Any help or additional resources would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am looking for a way to do a cubic spline interpolation between points, but have pre-defined first order derivatives and 0 second order derivative at the two ends. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have 6 equations (2 points, 2 first derivatives and 2 second derivatives) to satisfy, the interpolating spline will have 6 control points as well. This means that the spline could be a quintic Bezier curve, a quartic b-spline curve of 2 segments or a cubic b-spline curve of 3 segments.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have very little experience with splines. Why would I need anything with more than one segment to accomplish this? Also, if I understand what you are saying, I would have to (effectively) use a quintic curve to solve this. How would I begin to calculate a spline to satisfy the conditions? Feel free to just leave some resources for me if you believe that would better answer my question. I have searched but can't find anything of use.

Comment: If a quintic spline is good for you, you can use "quintic hermite" curve which is defined by 2 points, 2 first derivatives and 2 second derivatives. You can find out how to convert a quintic hermite curve to a quintic Bezier curve on the web.

Comment: How would I go about finding the equation for a quintic hermite spline? I can't seem to find the equations to calculate the coefficients based on these values anywhere. I have tried to derive them by hand, but I keep getting errors.

Comment: Try this link: https://www.google.com.tw/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.rose-hulman.edu/~finn/CCLI/Notes/day09.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjMpaeQ1czQAhWCWbwKHWu4CrQQFggYMAA&usg=AFQjCNFCn2VLFotyRINyQ0aMWYY9PbtFgg

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much.